# Is there any equivalence for $N \cap (\cup G_i) = ?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering if there is any equivalence for this,

> $$N \cap (\cup_{i = 1}^n G_i) = ?$$

and

> $$N \cap (\cup_{i=1}^\infty G_i) = ?$$

Comment: What do you mean by an equivalence? Also, is the union supposed to be $\bigcup_{i=1}^n G_i$?

Comment: One of the distributive laws immediately gives you $N\cap\bigcup_iG_i=\bigcup_i(N\cap G_i)$; did you want something other than that?

Comment: Thank you @BrianM.Scott, I am wondering if the distributive law applies to infinite case? I only see among three sets, and I believe it applies to finitely many ones.

Comment: Yes, it applies to arbitrary collections of sets; I’ve written up a short proof as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Brian! I edited the problem to make it more formal, but I don't think I changed my meanings. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tumbleweed: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{G}$ be any family of sets, and let $N$ be any set; then

$$N\cap\bigcup\mathscr{G}=\bigcup_{G\in\mathscr{G}}(N\cap G)\;.\tag{1}$$

To see this, suppose first that $x\in N\cap\bigcup\mathscr{G}$; then $x\in N$, and $x\in G$ for each $G\in\mathscr{G}$. But then $x\in N\cap G$ for each $G\in\mathscr{G}$, so $x\in\bigcup_{G\in\mathscr{G}}(N\cap G)$. Now suppose that $x\in\bigcup_{G\in\mathscr{G}}(N\cap G)$; then $x\in N\cap G$ for each $G\in\mathscr{G}$. But then $x\in N$, and $x\in G$ for each $G\in\mathscr{G}$, so $x\in N\cap\bigcup\mathscr{G}$. Thus, each side of $(1)$ is a subset of the other, and the two sets are therefore equal.